# How to continue the execution even if error happens

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-imaging-library

I have this code:

```py
from PIL import Image

image1 = Image.open(r'1.jpeg')
im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
im1.save(r'1.pdf')

# Part 2
image1 = Image.open(r'2.jpeg')
im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
im1.save(r'2.pdf')
```

And I want to make sure that part 2 of the code will run even if the first file doesn't exist, how can I do that?

Comment: perhaps a `try:` and `except:` block is what you are looking for? Here is a link that might help: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: If you "are a novice" then you should follow a tutorial from start to finish on the language basics first, and *then* think about using third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that like so:

```py
from PIL import Image

try:
    image1 = Image.open(r'1.jpeg')
    im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
    im1.save(r'1.pdf')
except OSError:
    print("first file doesn’t exist!")

image1 = Image.open(r'2.jpeg')
im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
im1.save(r'2.pdf')
```

To read more about `try-except` read here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the pass to the image exists and then proceed accordingly.

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path

imgPath = "1.jpeg"
if os.path.isfile(imgPath) :
    image1 = Image.open(r'1.jpeg')
    im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
    im1.save(r'1.pdf')
else:
    image1 = Image.open(r'2.jpeg')
    im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
    im1.save(r'2.pdf')
```